# Angular2 Firebase data grouping

Tags: angular, typescript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, angularfire

I would like to have a repeating data with a header for each new group.  My data model is pretty simple

```
{
  "-K_kNx9_F2-eTul8548y": {
    "title": "Registration",
    "startTime": "2017-02-04T08:00-06:00"
  },
  "-K_kQhBAJFTYEEqaXDp_": {
    "room": "Cafeteria",
    "startTime": "2017-02-04T12:00-06:00",
    "title": "Lunch",
    "track": "all"
  },
  ...
}
```

and I would love to have a div  like

```
<div *ngFor="**magic happens**">
  <h2>{{time.label}}</h2>
  <div *ngFor="let session of schedule | async">
    {{session.title}}
  </div>
</div>
```

I currently have a solution in place, but it does an ngFor for all time slots, and then hides the sessions where the times are not equal

[hidden]="!(session.startTime==time.time)"

But that is klunky and far from perfomant.  I also cannot seem to find anyway to have recurring queries with AngularFire.  Say, if I had a list of the starttimes, and then was able to recursively query Firebase.  That would work, but seem to not be a thing?  Currently my constructor is also very simple

```
export class ScheduleComponent {    
    schedule;
    times;
    constructor(public af: AngularFire) {
        this.schedule = af.database.list(PATH + '/schedule', { query: { orderByChild: 'title'} });
        this.times = af.database.list(PATH + "/scheduletimes");
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could modify your implementation to perform individual queries for each time by doing something like this:

```
import 'rxjs/add/operator/do';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';

export class ScheduleComponent {

    times;
    timesWithSchedules;

    constructor(public af: AngularFire) {

        // A list of times, as per your the code in your question:

        this.times = af.database.list(PATH + '/scheduletimes');

        // Compose an observable that adds the schedule for each time. Each
        // emitted value will be an array of time entries. Enumerate the array
        // and add an observable for the time's schedule:

        this.timesWithSchedules = this.times.do(times => times.forEach(time => {

            time.schedule = af.database

                // Query the schedule entries that correspond the time:

                .list(PATH + '/schedule', {
                    query: {
                        orderByChild: 'startTime'
                        startAt: time.time,
                        endAt: time.time
                    }
                })

                // Sort the emmitted array of sessions by title:

                .map(schedule => schedule.sort(compareTitles));

                function compareTitles(a, b) {
                    if (a.title < b.title) {
                        return -1;
                    }
                    if (a.title > b.title) {
                        return 1;
                    }
                    return 0;
                }
        }));
    }
}
```

Your template would then look like this:

```
<div *ngFor="let time of timesWithSchedules | async">
  <h2>{{time.label}}</h2>
  <div *ngFor="let session of time.schedule | async">
    {{session.title}}
  </div>
</div>
```